# Flask-WTF validate_on_submit() not executed

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am unable to figure out why my form will not validate. I have made sure that the CSRF field is inserted in to the HTML with `form.hidden_tag`

Here is the code for my registration form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo(password)])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

Here is the function in which I am checking to see if the form is validated. It does submit, as the program prints out 'submitted' into my terminal

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        print("submitted")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    print(forms.errors)
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

Using `forms.errors`, I get the following error message:

```
{'confirm_password': ["Invalid field name '<UnboundField(PasswordField, ('Password',), {'validators': [<wtforms.validators.DataRequired object at 0x00000205913D2F28>]})>'."]}
```

I am unsure of what this means.

If it helps, I have all my current code located on GitHub: https://github.com/tomajohnson21/FakeBook

Answer (score 9):

You are using the class member password instead of the "fieldname", thus you get the error.

**Incorrect:**

```
EqualTo(password)
```

**Correct:**

```
EqualTo('password')
```

There is an example of EqualTo in 
[WTForms validators documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#wtforms.validators.EqualTo)

Answer (score 1):

You can only put single quotes to password to solve it.

```
confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
```